# General conduction equation for 1D using Fourier's law

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, temperature

A product is coming out of a single hole die plate at a rate of 2g/s from a temperature of 98C to 10C. I want to know how long it takes to cool below 43C. The product is a cylindrical tube or radius of 7mm and can be broken into elements with length 10cm. The specific heat= 2 kJ/kg.k, thermal conductivity=0.4  and density=890kg/m3.

How do I derive the general conduction equation using fourier law of thermodynamics?

Comment: In this extrusion operation, is the rod passing through quench air or a cooling liquid?  Is the diameter constant, or is the rod being drawn down?  In all these cases, the heat transfer is going to be mainly radial, and each cross sections is experiencing transient radial cooling.

Comment: @ChetMiller the diameter is constant and in the extrusion operation the product coming out is a cooked starch product and it is unknown whether the product is passing through quench air or cooling liquid. We can assume it passing through air though

Comment: Is the quench air being blown across the rod, or is the rod just passing through stagnant air?

Comment: @ChetMiller rod is just passing through stagnant air from a temp of 98c to 10C

Comment: The key to this is getting the heat transfer coefficient on the outside of the rod which is going to play a large role in the overall heat transfer.  If you know the heat transfer coefficient, you can model the problem as a transient heat transfer to a cylinder, as reckoned by an observer traveling along with the rod.  But, to my knowledge, the correlation of the outside heat transfer coefficient is proprietary to different experts in the industry.

Comment: @ChetMiller we can assume the convection outside the cylinder with heat coefficient of 30W/m2.K

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99320/discussion-between-akhil-jain-and-chet-miller).

Comment: I'll formulate an answer tomorrow, it's very late *here* now.

Comment: @Gert yes please. That’ll be very helpful and kind of you.

Comment: How to derive the general heat conduction 1D equation can be found here: https://web.mit.edu/16.unified/www/FALL/thermodynamics/notes/node128.html. As ChetMiller pointed out though, you need to factor in that your rod is moving. Hope this helps!

Comment: Added another method.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the 1D Fourier conduction approach, there is another, simpler (but also more approximate) method: *lumped thermal analysis*.

Here we consider an infinitesimal element $\text{d}z$ to be thermally uniform, that is:

$$\frac{\partial T}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial T}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial T}{\partial z}$$

This means of course by Fourier that there's no conduction going on, only convection:

[image: Lumped analysis]

The 'go to' equation in the case of pure convection is of course [Newton's Law of Cooling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_law_of_cooling#Heat_transfer_version_of_the_law), generically:
$$Q=hA\Delta T$$
Applied to the infinitesimal element, which we'll follow as it travels down the $z$-axis:
$$\frac{\text{d}q}{\text{d}t}=2\pi R\text{d}zh(T-T_0)$$
with $T_0$ the surrounding temperature (constant).
$$\text{d}q=-\text{d}mc_p\text{d}T$$
Eliminating $\text{d}z$:
$$\text{d}m=\rho \text{d}V=\rho \pi R^2 \text{d}z$$
$$-\rho \pi R^2 c_p\text{d}z\frac{\text{d}T}{\text{d}t}=2h\pi R\text{d}z(T-T_0)$$
$$-\rho  R c_p\frac{\text{d}T}{\text{d}t}=2h(T-T_0)$$
$$\frac{\text{d}T}{T-T_0}=-\frac{2h}{\rho  R c_p}\text{d}t$$
$$\alpha=\frac{2h}{\rho  R c_p}$$
with $T_i$ the temperature after exiting the die plate.
$$\int_{T_i}^T\frac{\text{d}T}{T-T_0}=-\alpha \int_0^t\text{d}t$$
$$\frac{T-T_0}{T_i-T_0}=-\alpha t$$
$$\boxed{T=T_0+(T_i-T_0)\exp{(-\alpha t)}}$$
Time can be converted to length by means of the mass throughput.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I like this kind of mathematical-physical explanation. My sincere congratulations.

Comment: Thank you, Sebastiano.

Comment: I greatly appreciate both the able, capable, humble, and extraordinary people intellectually and spiritually.

Comment: @Gert is the method used for solving this called lumped thermal analysis?

Comment: Yes, that is what it is called, as I stated high up in the post.